# How to store selected items in pref

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I have custom alert dailog with list and check i am trying to store selected checkbox in pref,how to store selected item in shared preference,i am able to select values from list?can any one help me with this?

```
      class LoadAlldata extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterallstates;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestCountry.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            // pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            statedata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(STATE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    //  state_list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(COUNTRY_LIST);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(STATE_ID, c.getString(STATE_ID));
                        map.put(STATE_NAME, c.getString(STATE_NAME));
                        statedata.add(map);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return statedata;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            final String[] arrallstates = new String[statedata.size()];
            checked_state=new boolean[statedata.size()];
            for (int index = 0; index < statedata.size(); index++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = statedata.get(index);
                arrallstates[index] = map.get(STATE_NAME);
            }

            txtvw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View w) {



                     new AlertDialog.Builder(TestCountry.this)

                            .setTitle("Choose a Days")

                            .setMultiChoiceItems(arrallstates, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//storing the checked state of the items in an array
                                    checked_state[which] = isChecked;
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String display_checked_days = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrallstates.length; i++) {
                                        if (checked_state[i] == true) {
                                            display_checked_days = display_checked_days + " " + arrallstates[i];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(TestCountry.this, "The selected  is" + display_checked_days, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//clears the array used to store checked state
                                    for (int i = 0; i < checked_state.length; i++) {
                                        if (checked_state[i] == true) {
                                            checked_state[i] = false;
                                        }
                                    }
//used to dismiss the dialog upon user selection.
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).create().show();;
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you explain your problem in more details?

Comment: What do you mean by per id?

Comment: id once you select from activity B

Comment: i think you get problem when you checked all items and come back to activity A. Then again you redirect to B then before checked items not see. all item you get unchecked. is this your issue?

Comment: @rosy is your model class is parcelable?? you should pass same class object in adapter  when you click on filter button i think you create new object for it ans set in adapter so its clear

Comment: @rosy can i you put code on button click?

Comment: button click of activity A?

Comment: i have posted some code try it.

Answer (score 0):

First write a method to setSelection mannually in Adapter.

```
private int selectedItem = -1;

public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } // Here selectedItem is global variable
```

In onBindViewHolder add this code :

```
if (position == selectedItem){
 viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position));
 viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));
} else {
 viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isselected());
 viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));
}
```

From your Activity you have to call setSelectedItem(position) from your adapter insance. For getting position you have already know the chekbox Id so you can get position of that Id from List.

To get position from List:

```
private int getSelectedItem(List<String> stList, String name) {
  int pos = -1;
  for(int i=0; i<stList.size(); i++) {
   if(name.equals(stList.get(i)){
    pos = i;
    break;
   }
  }
 return pos;
}
```

Comment: i am getting id here,how it will match with my list data?  for(String name : namesList){
                    System.out.println("Testings"+name);
                }

Comment: what is the difference in if (position == selectedItem){

Comment: @rosy you're new to Android and development in general, right? And you expect someone to do all the work for you...

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: @NaveenKumarM check this http://pastie.org/10933289

viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position)); in this line it shows setchecked can not be aplied

Comment: @rosy what ever I answered you just put it in Your adapter class. Read my answer clearly

Comment: @NaveenKumarM yes i did that as per answer,check pastie

Comment: @rosy I given a code for your adapter and also for your activity. But you just did all code in your Adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120479/discussion-between-rosy-and-naveen-kumar-m).

Comment: @NaveenKumarM i created custom dailog with list and check, can you tell me how to use pref with that?

Comment: @NaveenKumarM did you check

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

First make model class with getter setter:

```
 private boolean checked;
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
```

And in Adapter Class in getview write Code like this.

```
FilterModelClass model=stList.get(position);
viewHolder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckUpdateListener(model));
```

Make class like below to handle checkedChangedListener

```
  /*******************
 * Checkbox Checked Change Listener
 ********************/

private final class CheckUpdateListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private final FilterModelClass model;

    private CheckUpdateListener(FilterModelClass model) {
        this.model = model;


    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.i("onCheckedChanged", "isChecked: " + isChecked);
        model.setChecked(isChecked);


        notifyDataSetChanged();




    }
}
```

Comment: what you posted ?? this is not good way to store every time in shared prefrences

Comment: you have to just create getter setter in model class for ischecked  boolean.

Comment: yeah :( ,,,can you chekc this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846286/arraylist-become-null

here it is storing in pref,but not getting selected value in button's click

Comment: yes i am student,and the code which i post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846286/arraylist-become-null..is able to store data in pref,but on my buttons click i am not able to get selected data

Comment: you get answer. you have approved.then whats problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120575/discussion-between-rosy-and-android-developer).