# Arraylist become null

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am getting id from previous activity,if id is null then i parse data and store it in arraylist,but if it is not null then i dont parse data and trying to set arraylist in listview,but it shows arraylist null

```
       mRecyclerView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filter_orderlist);
        makeJsonArrayRequestCountry();

    }


    private void makeJsonArrayRequestCountry() {

        showpDialog();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest( filter_url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("ress", response.toString());

                        filterList =new ArrayList<FilterModelClass>();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                String heder=obj.getString("filterName");

                                System.out.println("Hader"+heder);

                                JSONArray details=obj.getJSONArray("getParam");
                                for(int j=0;j<details.length();j++)
                                {

                                    JSONObject det=details.getJSONObject(j);
                                    FilterModelClass movie = new FilterModelClass();
                                    movie.setFilter_Name(det.getString("paramName"));
                                    String cityid=movie.setFilter_ID(det.getString("paramId"));
                                    filterList.add(movie);

                                }

                                mAdapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(FilterListActivity.this,filterList);
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                                btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        String data = "";
                                        List<FilterModelClass> stList = ((MyCustomBaseAdapter) mAdapter)
                                                .getStudentist();

                                        for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                                            FilterModelClass singleStudent = stList.get(i);
                                            if (singleStudent.isselected() == true) {

                                                data = data+singleStudent.getFilter_ID().toString()+",";

                                            }

                                        }
                                        Intent intent=new Intent();
                                        intent.putExtra("filterid",data);
                                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                                        FilterListActivity.this.finish();

                                        Toast.makeText(FilterListActivity.this,
                                                "Selected Students:" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();


                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data

                        hidepDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("ErrorVolley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();

            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(req, "jreq");
    }


    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {


            default:
                break;
        }

    }




    public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
        private  List<FilterModelClass> searchArrayList;
        ViewHolder holder;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        Context context;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<FilterModelClass> results) {
            context = mainActivity;
            searchArrayList = results;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return searchArrayList.size();

        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sorting_items, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                holder.cB = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

            holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getFilter_Name());

            holder.cB.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue" + position, false));
            holder.cB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + position, isChecked);
                    editor.commit();
                }});
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtName;
            CheckBox cB;
        }
        public List<FilterModelClass> getStudentist() {
            return searchArrayList;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I/System.out﹕ datacat nullnull

Comment: it should be 10-30 lines of stack trace

Comment: @Shubhank my app is not crashing, but recyclerview display nothing

Comment: where is filterList declared and initialized?

Comment: *but it shows arraylist null*.. how can you say this ? did you do any log or check ?

Comment: globally declared,and initialized in private void makeJsonArrayRequestCountry()

Comment: @Shubhank read the code: System.out.println("datacat null"+filterList);

Comment: @Shubhank here it shows null I/System.out﹕ datacat nullnull

Comment: @AlbAtNf too big lol, going by the description i thought it was a NPE.

Comment: @Shubhank no its not NPE,otherwise i can get issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set a `LayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView`: 
use this to set `LayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView`:

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

in oncreate

Comment: after `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); `

Comment: you can set before also @AshuKumar

Comment: Good point. I was not aware, that there is no default layoutManager. See the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager))

Comment: if(filtrid!=null)
        {

            filterList =new ArrayList<FilterModelClass>();
            System.out.println("datacat null"+filterList);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(filterList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

Comment: @ColdFire can you see that? i was trying that way,but then i found that,if service call everytime ,better to call it once.thats why i am trying to call json only one time

Comment: do you see the loading dialog and check whether you recieve the array in response

Comment: @ColdFire see my edited question,i able to manage via pref,but now issue is that not able to get selected item "Selected Students:" + data see here

Comment: well that is a different issue ,so you have to post another question for that,also please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: @ColdFire SO not allow me to post new question,thats why

Comment: @ColdFire can you check now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part

```
if(filtrid!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("datacat null"+filterList);
        mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(filterList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

You read the `filtrid` but you don't initialize your `filterList` in this case.

**EDIT**:

Retrieving the `filtrid`from the intent extras is not the same as populating the `filterList`. You could probably pass the filterList as JSON-String in the same way, you passed the `filtrid`. Then parse the JSON-String as you did already in `makeJsonArrayRequestCountry()`. A better way would be, to store the list persistent (SharedPreferences, SQL, ...), or don't store it at all. Just load the list from the server, whenever you start that activity.

Comment: whats the solution then?

Comment: i initialized as you said,but still recyclerview is empty

if(filtrid!=null)
        {

            filterList =new ArrayList<FilterModelClass>();
            System.out.println("datacat null"+filterList);
            mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(filterList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: I/System.out﹕ datacat null[]

Comment: because you did not put any data in that empty array. I am still trying to understand what you want to do with your code...